# How to get Microsoft.Windows.Photos installation path from Registry?

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I am working on an legacy application where I want to extract the full installation path of the `Microsoft.Windows.Photos.exe` path from the Windows Registry on Windows 10. Legacy code is using Windows registry API to extract the paths.What will be the best way to extract this path? Microsoft has shipped some applications with OS.[Provisioned Windows app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/apps-in-windows-10#provisioned-windows-apps).

Comment: What makes you think it is stored in the Registry? Traditional Win32 apps can get the user's Photos path by using `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_[COMMON_]MYPICTURES)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_[Public]Pictures)`

Comment: Actually I want Installation path of Mircosoft.Windows.photos.exe.

Comment: Scan folders with paths like "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_*_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"

Comment: Provisioned Windows app is not an application type. It's just applications that ship with the OS. The link you provided shows how to list provisioned applications. The source code should have enough information to solve your issue. Although it is an odd thing to want to know. It's much more common to want to launch the user's preferred application without having to know, which one it is or where it is installed. I would be surprised if Photos didn't register a protocol for activation.

Comment: @IInspectable Source code is based on windows 7 where Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jpeg\ShellNew has .jpeg key where default application is associated and its path is mentioned. Now we want the default application assoicated with JPEG on windows 10, and which is not present under the .jpeg key.

Comment: This is clearly an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem rephrase what you need in the first place

Comment: The solution on Windows 7 was [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw). Reaching into the registry never was. I won't be surprised, if `ShellExecuteEx` still works in Windows 10.